# Ansible inventory host file values in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

[image]

looking for ways to map replsetB to a hostname/ipaddress in the /etc/ansible/hosts inventory file? Goal is to be able to use the hosts in inventory  files in playbooks as variables

Comment: If I have a host file that has a value as "replsetB ansible_host=10.1.2.3". How can I use replsetB as a variable to use it as the hostname/ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

Please read: [How To Access Information About Other Hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

```
- debug:
    msg: "This is replsetB ip {{ hostvars['replsetB'].ansible_host }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! @Konstantin Suvorov